# CSS background-color applies to active state, but not normal state

Tags: css, html, background-color

I have added a button styling to a div. The background-color does not apply to the normal state. However, as soon as I click down on the button and turn it into an active state, the background-color applies correctly. I cannot figure out why the background-color only appears in one stage and not the other. I have resorted to using !important to make it work. Below is the CSS:

```
.statusbutton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #ffffff;
    height:43px;
    width:40px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#fbfbfb !important;
}


.statusbutton:active {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    top:1px;
}
```

EDIT: I realized the issue came from a later part of my stylesheet:

```
.red {
background:url(status-red.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

I applied .red to the button afterwards, which caused the background image to override the background-color. The code below ended up fixing the issue:

```
.red {
background:url(status-red.png) no-repeat center center;
background-color:#fbfbfb;
}
```

Comment: Do you tested it on every browser? Do you have this problem on a specific browser? Have you tried with different color to see if it works (actually you use the same color for both states and it's impossible to see if it works or not). I tried on Chrome and it works with both `<input>` and `<button>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brTUG/ Sounds like you have an issue with your CSS. Is there something that is overridding your normal statusbutton. Say another CSS declaration that include a parent element? Perhaps declared after?

Comment: It was being overridden by a later background image style. I placed the color and image together and it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using !important is usually a bad idea.  Is this your entire css file or is there more?  There may be another css style with higher priority that is overriding your attempts to set the background color here.  I would suggest setting up a jsfiddle if you're still having trouble

Comment: You were right! There was a later background image styling that overrode the background color. I put the image and color stylings together and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this code works, you have to remove the `!important` from your CSS code otherwise this rule will take priority on the `:active` state, and remember to change the colors in both states (actually you use `#fbfbfb` for both normal and active state).

Comment: Was the first time I resorted to !important... never again :)